# Display Category data in MVC PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP MVC PIP framework to build sample website. I am facing issue when i am trying to show my gallery `category` wise.

Gallery shall look like as below:

```
Category 1:
<img src='Image1' />  <img src='Image2' />    <img src='Image3' />  .. so on
   Desc1                    Desc2                   Desc3  .. so on

Category 2:
<img src='Image4' />          <img src='Image5' />  .. so on
       Desc4                        Desc5  .. so on
```

`photo_category Table`

[image]

`photogallery Table`

[image]

My Gallery  Model:

```
class Gallery_Photo extends Model {

public function photosCategory()
{
     $result = $this->query('SELECT * FROM `photo_category` WHERE status = "A" ');
     return $result;
}
public function photosGallery()
{
    $result = $this->query('SELECT * FROM `photogallery` WHERE status = "A" ORDER BY pcID ');
    return $result;
}

}
```

I am not getting how to pass id from photo_category table to photogallery table in Model itself or how can i call model function in view.

If someone wants to see my PDO class, [click here](http://txt.do/5ne60)

Output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($result);` can be seen here [click here](http://txt.do/5nej6)

Comment: @YourCommonSense PDO code is based on your suggestion

Comment: @Anant .. please see output.. written in question

Comment: Its not an image... it is plain text file that has shared... and to know PIC category, you can refer to `pcID` column. This refers to ID in `photo_category` table... and we have to combine the tables by JOIN to get name if category

Comment: and why is that... all is now available to u :)